# MySQL: How to SELECT a row from the 1st table if there is no matching row in the 2nd table

Tags: mysql, select, join, compare

Table 1(number primary key):

- id-1, number-123, name-asd
- id-2, number-124, name-asd

Table 2(number can be duplicated, id pk):

- id-1, number-123, name-asd
- id-2, number-123, name-das
- id-3, number-124, name-rrr
- id-4, number-124, name-asx

Wanted output:

```
124, asd
```

I have to compare the 1st table rows with the rows in 2nd table.

If row 1 is not equal to each row in the second where `a.number = b.number` then we should execute `select * from table1`.

If we find a matching row (between table 1 and table 2) then we should not execute the select query found above.

UPDATE:
How can I compare 3 tables like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple select left joining the two tables, and filtering for rows where there is no data for the 2nd table should give your desired results.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.number = b.number AND a.name = b.name
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: It should have output only one row for number = 124 since there aren't any matches between the two for number = 124 AND name = asd.

Comment: looks like it working:)) without where b.id is null it gives me wrong could you explain how Where b.id is NULL working?

Comment: Since it uses  left join, all rows from the first table will be included. The WHERE b.id IS NULL removes any rows where the ON clause didn't find a matching row in the 2nd table. For rows returned by table 1, the columns in table 2 will all be null.

Comment: Don;'t forget to accept the answer if it's working for you.

Comment: should i click "answer your question" below? or how to do that?

Comment: Should be on the left near the vote up/down of the answer.

Comment: Should say something like "accept this answer", maybe when you mouse over it. Haven't seen it a long time.

Comment: could you tell me how can i do that for 3 tables? currently i compare two and insert in temporary, and compare temporary with 3rd

Comment: Add another *LEFT JOIN* for the 3rd table and add another clause for the 3rd table in the where table..